# How can I receive email notifications about reactions to my own content on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

Which email notification settings do I need to enable to receive email notifications about reactions (comments) to my published posts and status messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

**Settings** -> **Notifications** -> **Email** -> **All notifications, except the ones you unsubscribe from**

This will notify you by email about reactions. There is no special settings for reactions.